# How to have menus (website style navigation links) in java desktop application

Tags: java, user-interface, menu

I am using Netbeans and i want to develop a java desktop application. The application should be like a website somehow, i mean i want to have some menus in my java desktop application which by clicking on each one of those menus i should be able to access some different pages with different contains(like having main-menu, report-menu….). 
Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) based sample, which generates a menu based on a set of [hyperlinks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) to different content items.  This is quite similar to how a lot of web pages work.  The sample is styled via [css](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), similar to a web page.

The sample creates the scene content in Java code, but you could construct the layouts and define the content items in [fxml](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) generated by the [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) tool if you prefer.

JavaFX also has traditional application [menu bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/menu_controls.htm) and [tab panes](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html) as well (not demonstrated in this sample).

*Sample program output, with some different links clicked:*

[image: sugar]
[image: coffee]

*Sample code:*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Displays content panes activated by a hyper-link based navigation bar
 */
public class HyperlinkedNavMenu extends Application {
    private LinkContent[] linkContent;

    private final StackPane content = new StackPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        linkContent = createLinkContent();

        content.setPrefWidth(200);
        HBox.setHgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setTitle("Capello Pazzo");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createLayout()));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Pane createLayout() {
        HBox layout = new HBox(
                10,
                createNavBar(), 
                content
        );
        
        layout.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("nav.css").toExternalForm()
        );
        
        return layout;
    }

    private VBox createNavBar() {
        VBox nav = new VBox();
        nav.setMinWidth(100);
        nav.getStyleClass().add("navbar");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < linkContent.length; i++) {
            Hyperlink link = createLink(
                    linkContent[i].linkText, 
                    createContentNode(linkContent[i])
            );
            nav.getChildren().add(link);
            if (i == 0) {
                link.fire();
            }
        }

        return nav;
    }

    private Node createContentNode(LinkContent linkContent) {
        Label label = new Label(linkContent.contentText);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        
        VBox contentNode = new VBox(
                10,
                new ImageView(linkContent.image),
                label
        );
        contentNode.getStyleClass().add("contentnode");
        
        return contentNode;
    }

    private Hyperlink createLink(final String linkText, final Node contentNode) {
        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(linkText);
        link.setOnAction(t -> content.getChildren().setAll(
                contentNode
        ));
        
        return link;
    }

    private static class LinkContent {
        final String linkText, contentText;
        final Image image;

        LinkContent(String linkText, String contentText, String imageLoc) {
            this.linkText = linkText;
            this.contentText = contentText;
            this.image = new Image(imageLoc);
        }
    }

    // icon license:     http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/
    // icon attribution: http://www.iconarchive.com/artist/archigraphs.html
    private LinkContent[] createLinkContent() {
        return new LinkContent[] {
                new LinkContent(
                        "Lorem",
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/tea-party/128/Sugar-Cubes-icon.png"
                ),
                new LinkContent(
                        "Vestibulum",
                        "Vestibulum a dui et massa laoreet vehicula.",
                        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/tea-party/128/Tea-Cake-icon.png"
                ),
                new LinkContent(
                        "Donec",
                        "Donec sed euismod risus.",
                        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/tea-party/128/Tea-Cup-icon.png"
                ),
                new LinkContent(
                        "Duis",
                        "Duis semper porttitor leo ac posuere.",
                        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/tea-party/128/Tea-Pot-icon.png"
                )
        };
    }
}
```

*Sample css:*

```
/** file: nav.css
 * place in same directory as HyperlinkedNavMenu.java and have your build system copy it
 * to the same location as HyperlinkedNavMenu.java.class */

.root {
    -fx-background-image: url("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/linen_fabric_background_04_hd_picture_169825.jpg");
    -fx-padding: 15; 
    -fx-font-size: 15;
}

.navbar {
    -fx-background-color: burlywood, peachpuff; 
    -fx-background-radius: 10, 10; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2; 
    -fx-font-style: italic; 
    -fx-padding: 10 15 15 10; 
}

.contentnode {
    -fx-background-color: aliceblue; 
    -fx-padding: 15 20 20 15;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, slategrey, 10, 0, 5, 5);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like `Netbeans` it gives facility of `menu bar`, `menu` and `menu item` you can drag and drop the `menu bar` over `JFrame` and add menus and menu items to it.

OR

You can use card layout to show multiple frames in a single place.