# How to load new fxml content into a Pane on menu item selection?

Tags: java, controller, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

My JavaFX and FXML application loads is as follows:

1. A login screen. Once the credentials are input the login stage closes and the MainGui.FXML launches with its own controller: MainGuiController.java
2. MainGuiController also calls controllers for other GUIs because so far in my scene, all I have is a menu and a blank main body. When a menu item is selected a  Connection object is passed to the new stage's controller and the stage opens up in a new window. So far so good.

However, I was thinking of changing the design and having the content that's displayed from menu interaction displayed in the empty body portion beneath my menu. I don't like the idea of having many stages open with the potential for NPEs because I do have a database that I work with.

How do I add new content [from existing FXML files] to a blank anchor pane underneath my menu every time a menu item is selected?

Comment: Related question: [How to have menus in java desktop application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556637/how-to-have-menus-in-java-desktop-application)

Comment: Thanks!

I took a slightly different approach. I realized I could pass the main scene and stage as parameters to the main controller's constructor and from there just load an fxml file directly into my anchor pane...

Wow, I just realized I didn't even frame the title of the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

And just for information, you can easily include one fxml file into another fxml file. for ref:
[fxml include](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)

Comment: thaks Shreyas! Didn't know about fxml include