# Unable to get Scene from MenuItem in JavaFX

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx, fxml

I am trying to change the scene in a javafx stage based on menuItem click. Here is my sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="560.0" styleClass="background" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
    <MenuBar layoutY="0.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="300.0" useSystemMenuBar="false" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0">
      <menus>
        <Menu id="manageAccountsMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onManageAccountsMenuActionPerformed" text="Accounts" fx:id="manageAccountsMenu">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onTweetsMenuActionPerformed" text="Manage" fx:id="manageAccountsSubmenuItem" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onTweetsMenuActionPerformed" text="Tweets" fx:id="tweetsMenuItem" />
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Retweets" />
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <VBox id="VBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="24.0" spacing="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
      <children>
        <ScrollPane id="ScrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefViewportHeight="400.0" prefViewportWidth="300.0">
          <content>
            <TableView prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="SNO" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="200.0" text="Account" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="200.0" text="Status" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Actions" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
          </content>
        </ScrollPane>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Account" textAlignment="CENTER">
          <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
              <image>
                <Image url="@addAccount.png" />
              </image>
            </ImageView>
          </graphic>
        </Button>
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@darkTheme.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    protected void onManageAccountsMenuActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Manage Accbtnclick");
//        Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
//        Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
//
//        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//        stage.setScene(scene);
//        stage.show();
    }
    @FXML
    protected void onTweetsMenuActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Manage Accbtnclick");
    Node node= (Node)event.getSource();
    Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
    Scene scene = Main.screens.get("tweet");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Here is my Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static HashMap<String,Scene> screens=new HashMap<String,Scene>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent accountScreen= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            Parent tweetScreen=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tweetform.fxml"));
            //Parent retweetScreen=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("retweetform.fxml"));
            screens.put("account",new Scene(accountScreen));
            screens.put("tweet",new Scene(tweetScreen));
            //screens.put("retweet",new Scene(retweetScreen));
            stage.setTitle("Manage Accounts");
            stage.setScene(screens.get("account"));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I click on the menuItem Manage under Accounts Menu, I get the following exception:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7541 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\rahulserver\IdeaProjects\DrawingText\out\production\DrawingText;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain sample.Main
Manage Accbtnclick
Manage Accbtnclick
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:456)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1188)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1139)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$6.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1137)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3328)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:269)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node
    at sample.Controller.onTweetsMenuActionPerformed(Controller.java:29)
    ... 50 more
```

So how do I get the containing stage/scene from the menu Item clicked event handler?

**EDIT**
The line

```
Node node= (Node)event.getSource();
```

in controller.java is line number 29 which is giving problems.

Comment: *`java.lang.NullPointerException at sample.Controller.onTweetsMenuActionPerformed(Controller.java:30)`* => where is line 30 of your Controller.java class?

Comment: @assylias Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

Comment: My guess is that `node` is not visible hence does not have a Window. You could try to debug the code to check the variables at that point.

Comment: @assylias I have revised stacktrace and the controller. This should giv u better idea.

Comment: @assylias see the line number 29 in edit again...

Comment: rahul see this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321167/vertical-menu-for-configuration-panel/18327570#18327570

Answer (score 22):

Your real error is shown in the second to last line of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.MenuItem cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Node
    at sample.Controller.onTweetsMenuActionPerformed(Controller.java:29)
```

This error is referring to the following line from your controller:

```
Node node= (Node)event.getSource();
```

Looking at the JavaFX API Docs, neither MenuItem nor Menu are subclasses of Node.  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html

I would suggest grabbing the source as an Object, then checking its type before continuing.  Also, I ran into problems using the getSource() method; the getTarget() method worked better for me.  Either way, you still need a way to get the to the Stage.

To do this, you might want to use the `fx:id` tag in your FXML instead of the `id` tag.  This will allow you to inject the FXML elements directly into your controller.  For example, you could grab the Stage from the MenuBar (which is a subclass of Node) by injecting the MenuBar element into your controller.

In the FXML:

```
<MenuBar fx:id="myMenuBar" layoutY="0.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="300.0" useSystemMenuBar="false" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="2.0">
```

In the controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML MenuBar myMenuBar;
    ...
    @FXML
    protected void onTweetsMenuActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Manage Accbtnclick");
        Stage stage = (Stage) myMenuBar.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene scene = Main.screens.get("tweet");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    ...
}
```

You may need to do a bit of tweaking here, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Sounds great. +10 for u. But wuld confirm it as the answer after giving a try.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaFX 15.0.1, you can use getOwnerWindow to get the Stage and get the Scene from the stage.

```
Stage owner = (Stage)menuItem.getParentPopup().getOwnerWindow();
Scene scene = owner.getScene();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the `Scene` and `Window` based on a menu item being clicked without it being an injected FXML element, or without referencing it if you did create it with FXML. In other words by using the `Event`'s target.

In my problem I had a `MenuButton` with a dropdown menu (a `ContextMenu` as I found out, which I didn't know as I had created my menu in FXML) containing `MenuItems` and I wanted to open a `FileChooser`, which needs the `Window` as an argument, when the "Save" `MenuItem` was clicked.

Normally I would have gone down the route of getting the event's target, then the Parent, then the next Parent etc. and finally the Scene and then Window. As `Menu` and `MenuItem` are not `Node`s and therefore do not have `Parent`s In this case however I did the following:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)event.getTarget();
ContextMenu cm = menuItem.getParentPopup();
Scene scene = cm.getScene();
Window window = scene.getWindow();

fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
```

Or, converting the bulk into a one line argument:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

fileChooser.showSaveDialog(((MenuItem)event.getTarget()).getParentPopup().getScene().getWindow());
```

Just adapt this as necessary based on your own scene-graph (i.e. how many parents you need to get through in cases of sub-menus etc) and what you are wanting to do once you have the `Window`, but once you get to the `ContextMenu` (the popup list of `MenuItems`), you can get the `Scene` and then from that get the `Window`.

As an aside, here is the FXML I used to create my `MenuButton`, and hence why I didn't realise I had to get the `ContextMenu` through a call to `getParentPopup()` without some trial and error:

```
<MenuButton fx:id="menu" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="35.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6600ff; -fx-border-width: 0; -fx-mark-color: white; -fx-padding: 5;" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" underline="true">
    <items>
        <MenuItem fx:id="newSearch" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Search" onAction="#clearSearch" />
        <SeparatorMenuItem  />
        <MenuItem fx:id="saveSearch" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save Search" onAction="#saveSearch" />
        <MenuItem fx:id="loadSearch" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load Search" />
        <SeparatorMenuItem  />
        <MenuItem fx:id="saveResults" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save Results" />
        <MenuItem fx:id="loadResults" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load Results" />
        <SeparatorMenuItem />
        <MenuItem fx:id="exportResults" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Export Results" />
    </items>
    <font>
        <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
    </font>
</MenuButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) myMenuBar).getScene().getWindow();

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer

Comment: The question is about menu item, not menu bar.