# Javafx run another class using hyperlink

Tags: javafx

I have class A and B.
In Class A, there's a hyperlink abc ="Go to B"
When you click that hyperlink, class B should be launched.
I tried 
`abc.setOnAction(e->Application.launch(B.class));`
But it doesnt work.
Need to code this hyperlink using only `JavaFX`. No `FXML` or any other types.

Comment: can you define "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is absolutely on topic, but too broad as it currently stands - I'm afraid we've no way of knowing what's wrong unless you post a [mcve].

Comment: Either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556637/how-to-have-menus-website-style-navigation-links-in-java-desktop-application) or `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(yourRootNode));`